# How to "grab" contents inside a class tag and display the content using only javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not sure if I am on the right direction, but what I am trying to achieve is quite complexe, at least to me. So What I am looking for is to find the content inside a html class tag and display this content wherever I want. Lets take an example of an online product on a website, and supposing that on the title the code is written as following:

```
< h2 class="Title">This is a product example< /h2>|| note the space had
  to be to show the exact code.
```

Yes, I know that i could just use the variable like:

```
 < h2>$title< /h2>
```

But what if don't have access to it? Is there any chance of getting them details using :getElementByClassName
And then display that content? I have been looking all over and I, unfortunately got nothing, therefore decided to ask here.

HTML:

```
<div id="container"> ABC <br />
<p class="displayThis"> I want this to be displayed again
using only JavaScript </p
</div>
```

Style:

```
 
    #container {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    background: #999;
    border-color: #fc0000;
    text-align: center;
   }
.displayThis {
    background: #999;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

.newContent {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10%;
    right: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

Script:

```
var displayThys = document.getElementByClassName("displayThis");

document.write('\<p class="newContent">'+ displayThys +'</p>\ <br />\ ');
```

**Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98Fx8/)**

Comment: First, not sure why you'd want to store content inside a class but alright. Second, do you want to achieve this with pure JS or is jQuery acceptable?

Comment: Are you using jQuery or not? You have included it in your tag but in your code you use vanilla JS.

Comment: StackOverflow does not normally use `<pre>` for formatting. Your space woes could be avoided by surrounding inline code with backticks (`), or by indenting multi-line code four spaces (also available through visual selection followed by Ctrl-K (or Cmd-K on Mac).

Comment: Thanks. I don't think jQuery will be acceptable. @Zero21xxx As I said, this is an example as I have not the code done. Anyways, I will try and update whether i success or not. Thanks for your comments and answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="container"> ABC <br />
    <p class="displayThis"> I want this to be displayed again using only JavaScript </p>
</div>
```

And here is the script

```
<script>
    (function(){
        var a = document.getElementsByClassName("displayThis");

        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        var displayAgain = a[i];
        document.write('\<p class="newContent">'+ displayAgain.innerHTML +'</p>\ <br />\ ');

        }
    })();
</script>
```

---

The code itself is quite self-explanatory

Comment: Much simpler to just clone the node and attach it to the DOM as as sibling, e.g. in the for loop:`displayAgain.parentNode.appendChild(displayAgain.cloneNode(true));`. QED :-) Note that the [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) created by [*getElementsByClassName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyclassname) is **live** so this will create an infinite number of clones. Better to store the value of *i* rather than get it every time.

Comment: Yes it is create infinite clones. So what to do with them if you could easily append the text using innerHTML to a new element with different class? I dont get it, noob here :D

Comment: Thanks. I will work on that code and If i get any further problems, i should update you.